# Can't readline() without crashing my Android app

Tags: java, android, tabs, readline

I'm building an app that takes in website data and simply displays it. I had it working but then I tried to implement it into a tabbed UI and it's now not working.

I've narrowed it down to be

```
    input = reader.readLine();
```

that is the cause but I don't understand what's going wrong.

**Main Class**

```
package app.stockup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import app.stockup.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class Main extends TabActivity
{
public static ArrayList<ShareSet> sharePortfolio = new ArrayList<ShareSet>();

Resources resources;
TabHost tabHost;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    resources = getResources();
    tabHost = getTabHost();


    buildPortfolio();
    buildPage(Status.class, "Status", R.drawable.status_tab);
    buildPage(Portfolio.class, "Portfolio", R.drawable.portfolio_tab);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}

private void buildPage(Class<? extends Activity> className, String tabName, int tabID)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, className);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(tabName)
           .setIndicator(tabName, resources.getDrawable(tabID))
           .setContent(intent));
}

private void buildPortfolio()
{       
    sharePortfolio.add(new ShareSet("BLVN", "Bowleven", 3960, R.id.portfolioTextBLVN, R.id.statusTextBLVN));
    sharePortfolio.add(new ShareSet("BP", "British Petroleum", 192, R.id.portfolioTextBP, R.id.statusTextBP));
    sharePortfolio.add(new ShareSet("EXPN", "Experian", 258, R.id.portfolioTextEXPN, R.id.statusTextEXPN));
    sharePortfolio.add(new ShareSet("HSBA", "HSBC", 343, R.id.portfolioTextHSBC, R.id.statusTextHSBC));
    sharePortfolio.add(new ShareSet("MKS", "Marks & Spencers", 485, R.id.portfolioTextMS, R.id.statusTextMS));
    sharePortfolio.add(new ShareSet("SN", "Smith & Nephew", 1219,     R.id.portfolioTextSN, R.id.statusTextSN));
}
}
```

**Status Class**

```
package app.stockup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import app.stockup.Main;
import app.stockup.ShareSet;
import app.stockup.WebReader;
import app.stockup.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Status extends Activity
{   
private ArrayList<ShareSet> myShares = Main.sharePortfolio;
Iterator<ShareSet> iterator = myShares.iterator();

ShareSet mySet;

TextView connectionStatus, fieldID;

int color;
WebReader reader;

double currentPrice;
double openPrice;
double difference;

String input;
String percentage;
String shareDirection;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.status);
    connectionStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus); 
    connectionStatus.setText("Internet : Connected");
    compareSharePrice();
}

public void compareSharePrice()
{       
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        mySet = iterator.next();
        fieldID = (TextView)findViewById(mySet.getStatusFieldID());
        reader = new WebReader(mySet.getStockURL());
        input = reader.readLine();
        currentPrice = reader.getCurrentPrice(input);
        openPrice = reader.getOpenPrice(input);
        difference = Math.abs(openPrice - currentPrice);
        percentage = String.format("%.2f", 100/(openPrice/difference));

        if(currentPrice >= openPrice)
        {
            color = (int) Color.GREEN;
            shareDirection = "rocketed";
        }

        else if(currentPrice <= openPrice)
        {
            color = (int) Color.RED;
            shareDirection = "plummeted";
        }

        fieldID.setText(mySet.getStockCode() + " has " + shareDirection + " by " + percentage + "%");
        fieldID.setTextColor(color);
    }
}
}
```

**WebReader Class**

```
package app.stockup;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WebReader
{
private static Scanner scanner;

int trade;
int from;
int to;

String price;

public WebReader(URL url)
{
    try
    {
        URLConnection website = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = website.getInputStream();
        scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    {

    }
}

public String readLine()
{
    if (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {           
        return scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }

    return null;
}

public double getCurrentPrice(String input)
{
    trade = input.indexOf("Last Trade:", 0);
    from = input.indexOf("<b><span", trade); 
    from = input.indexOf(">", from + 4);        
    to = input.indexOf("</span></b>", from);        
    price = input.substring(from + 1, to); 
    return Double.parseDouble(price); 
} 
/*
 * 
 */
public double getOpenPrice(String input)
{
    trade = input.indexOf("Open:", 0);
    from = input.indexOf("><td class", trade);
    from = input.indexOf(">", from + 4);        
    to = input.indexOf("</td></tr>", from);     
    price = input.substring(from + 1, to);
    return Double.parseDouble(price);
}
}
```

Comment: What's the exception or error you're getting?

Comment: When I tried to read the data in a different way I used a try catch and it kept giving me IOException errors. I thought that maybe the URL was incorrect but it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that `scanner` never gets created in the `WedReader` constructor. Do *something* useful in the `catch` block in that constructor, even if you just write out over ADB so you know that it failed.

Comment: If the code for that part hasn't changed since the last program why would it fail now? Literally the only thing that has changed is the use of tabs.

Comment: I have no idea, but still, check that your constructor runs without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `Scanner.hasNextLine()` and `Scanner.next()` :

```
if (scanner.hasNextLine())
{           
    return scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
}
```

That will cause a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` exception to be thrown on the last line of input. They treat lines differently for tokenization.

Use:

```
return scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").nextLine();
```

Comment: Do you mean to replace the single line or the if statement?

Comment: Replace the line that starts with `return`.

Answer (score -1):

```
catch (IOException ioe) 
    {

    }
```

Whatever the problem is, it is being masked by your failure to do print, log, or do anything else useful with this exception. *Never* ignore an exception, and while I'm ranting, *always* print or log the exception itself, not just your own made-up error message.